# How to change Select List values based on other Select List value?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Let's say I have 2 Select List items on page. Both lists should be static. I am able to set first list items statically:

```
STATIC2:Lab1;1,Lab2;2,Lab3;3
```

Now based on this selection, I want second list to show one of the value sets:

```
for 1 in first list => STATIC2:One;1,Two;2,Three;3
for 2 in first list => STATIC2:Apple;1,Pear;2,Orange;3
for 3 in first list => STATIC2:None;-1
```

Basically no query from tables is required. How can I achieve this? What parameters my items should have and/or script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me, I think easiest way here is to create table/query for second static list. Something like this:

```
with LOV2 as (select 1  return_value, 'One' display_name, 1 lov1_id from dual union all
              select 2, 'Two',   1 lov1_id from dual union all
              select 3, 'Three', 1 lov1_id from dual union all
              select 1, 'Apple', 2 lov1_id from dual union all
              select 2, 'Pear',  2 lov1_id from dual union all
              select 3, 'Orange',2 lov1_id from dual union all
              select 1, 'Almost none', 3 lov1_id from dual union all
              select 2, 'None',   3 lov1_id from dual)
select display_name, return_value
  from LOV2
 where lov1_id = :P_LOV1_VALUE
```

And use this query as source of LOV2.

**UPD**

Go to `Shared Components` -> `User Interface` -> `Lists of Values`. Click `Create`, then `From scratch`. Then you can see a field `Type`, where you can select static or dynamic type. Static list is a list where you directly values to display and return values. Dynamic list is a result of SQL query. Every list have two fields: `display_value` - a value which user see on the screen and `return value` - a value which you will get in your PL/SQL code. Also LOV can be `named` - it is a LOV, created in `Shared Components` section (you can use it on many pages, and when you change it, it will changed everywhere). To use named LOV on a page open item's properties, in section `LIST of Values` choose name of required LOV in field `Named LOV`.
My query above is a source for dynamic LOV, you can create a named LOV with it or use in LOV definition on a page.

Comment: Dmitry, few clarifications. What will be the `Page Action when Value Changed` for first LOV? I understand this query goes to `Source value or expression` for second LOV? then what is the Source type for second LOV? Also for second LOV what is the `List of values definition`?

Comment: 1. To update second LOV you can use any way - dynamic action or submit (submit is easier). You can make button for submit or make submit when value changed (`Page Action when Value Changed` - `Submit page` as I remember). 2. Second LOV here is ordinary dynamic LOV, you can create named dynamic LOV or use this query directly in the page, it will work in both cases.

Comment: Dmitry, sorry for delay. Second LOV as well as first are type of "Select List". Not sure what is named dynamic LOV, assuming you mean programmatically create control using APEX_ITEM. As `List of values definition` I've set your query. Source is empty. The result is following: After changing item in first LOV, in second I can see only numbers, not strings. Also, what is representing `LOV2` in your query? Does it imply to current component variable?

Comment: @Pablo I thought you already know all of this. I added some explanations to my answer. You saw only numbers because of I mixed up fields `display_value` and `return_value` in my query, now I corrected it.

Comment: Dmitry, as always excellent answer. All works like a charm! Thanks!